# I am not getting user current running location after Terminate the Application

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkmapview

I require the user running location and route map path, When an application is `Terminate` or `Background` mode.

Currently I am using significant location for application kill mode, but we are not getting proper distance and route.
Because `didUpdateLocations` is called after some specific interval so that I am not getting proper distance.
Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple docs :

> Apps can expect a notification as soon as the device moves 500 meters
>   or more from its previous notification. It should not expect
>   notifications more frequently than once every five minutes. If the
>   device is able to retrieve data from the network, the location manager
>   is much more likely to deliver notifications in a timely manner.

This is why `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()` would not work reliably for tracking user location change other than driving/public-transport.

Now, coming back to your problem of having to track user location when app is terminated, unfortunately you cannot track location when the app is terminated

> If your app is terminated either by a user or by the system, the system doesn’t automatically restart your app when new location updates arrive. A user must explicitly relaunch your app before the delivery of location updates resumes. The only way to have your app relaunched automatically is to use region monitoring or the significant-change location service.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But, One of the App Evelance. It's working fine in  both Senior (Terminate or Background mode).https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/everlance-mileage-log-tracker/id985378916?mt=8

Comment: Yeah. They probably monitor significant location changes. Now since it's an app to track car mileage it works alright (app is relaunched, location update is sent every 500m) but this wouldn't work for your app since it requires more accuracy over short distances. I've highlighted this in my answer.